# Intellij idea showing error: could not create the java virtual machine

Tags: android, intellij-idea, jvm, fatal-error, dex

I am having trouble with `intellij idea` ide.
It was working fine , but suddenly it started showing error:

```
Android Dex: [untitled3] Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Android Dex: [untitled3] Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I have checked my sdk, jdk path.
i have done `re-installing` it but still the problem is same.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was caused by the too high heap size for the DX compiler, [it can be changed here](http://img405.imageshack.us/img405/4058/7ghu.png) (`File` | `Settings` | `Compiler` | `Android DX Compiler`).

[Check this document](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23393413) that explains why it happens when 32-bit JDK is used.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

navigate to C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.3\bin and run the  " idea64.exe ".

if 64-bit executable is not provided for your product
Start the IDE using .bat file instead of the .exe

Answer (score 0):

`javac` may be running in 32-bit mode, preventing the use of heaps greater than 2**32 bytes.

[Try adding `-d64` to the “Additional compiler process VM options”](https://superuser.com/questions/654821/force-64-bit-java-in-os-x)  in settings or via Ctrl-Shift-A/⇧⌘A