# Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. intelli idea ubuntu 20.04

Tags: java, ubuntu, intellij-idea, jvm, ubuntu-20.04

[image]

[image]

trying to raise a project on my new laptop I have the error
Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Yes, I have java installed, only the project compiles perfectly when I give maven install, the problem is at the time of deployment

I have already tried changing the memory as indicated here ([Intellij idea showing error: could not create the java virtual machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18095117/intellij-idea-showing-error-could-not-create-the-java-virtual-machine/18103499#18103499)) without results

Comment: Please show the full command line of your application with all the options.

Comment: Adding the environment variable directly to the IDE hasn't worked either.

Comment: Post text rather than images.